# Dingo API routing does not pass in GET parameters when routing to controller

Tags: laravel, api, dingo-api

I have a Laravel Application and it uses Dingo Router:

```
 $api->get('/cash-flow', 'App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@cashFlowReport');
```

When my front-end calls this api, it gets 200 responses from OPTIONS & GET.  However, it does not successfully pass in the GET variables.

```
 public function cashFlowReport(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    return var_dump($input);
}
```

The response returns an empty array.  I thought it was the Request class dependency but I think it would throw an error when it tries to access the parameter.

I have the Request Dependency:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: are you using nginx?

Comment: Yes I am @lagbox,

Comment: can you please provide the `try_files` line from the `location /` block of the site configuration file?

Comment: Yup this was it.  I saw it on another post.  I had to add $variable to the end

Comment: yea that was where i was going with that ... you should have just replied to my question and saved yourself an hour ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using nginx you will want to make sure the query string is actually making it through the 'rewrite'/'pretty url' process.

From the Laravel installation documentation for Pretty Urls:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

The `?$query_string` part is important.

[Laravel Docs - Installation - Pretty Urls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#pretty-urls)